# ReactNative UI freezing for a second before rendering a component with a fetch in useEffect()

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

TL;DR: My UI freezes for .5-1s when I  try to render a component that does a API fetch within a `useEffect()`.

I have ComponentX which is a component that fetches data from an API in a useEffect() via a redux dispatch. I'm using RTK to build my redux store.

```
function ComponentX() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchListData()); // fetch list data is a redux thunk.
  }, [dispatch]);
  
  ... 
  return <FlatList data={data} /> // pseudo code
}
```

as you can see the fetch will happen everytime the component is rendered.

Now I have `ComponentX` in `App` along with another component called `ComponentY`.

Here's a rudamentary implementation on how my app determines which component to show. Pretend each component has a button that executes the `onClick`

```
function App() {
  const [componentToRender, setComponentToRender] = useState("x");

  if (componentToRender === "x") {
    return <ComponentX onClick={() => setComponentToRender("y")}/>
  } else {
    return <ComponentY onClick={() => setComponentToRender("x")}/>
  }

}
```

Now the issue happens when I try to move from `ComponentY` to `ComponentX`. When I click the "back" button on `ComponentY` the UI will freeze for .5-1s then show `ComponentX`. Removing the `dispatch(fetchListData());` from the useEffect fixes the issue but obviously I can't do that since I need the data from the API.

Another fascinating thing is that I tried wrapping the dispatch in an if statement assuming that it would prevent a data fetch thus resolving the "lag" when `shouldReload` is false. The UI still froze before rendering `ComponentX`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldReload) { // assume this is false
      console.log("reloading");
      dispatch(fetchListData());

    }
  }, [dispatch, shouldReload]);
```

Any idea what's going on here?

EDIT:

I've done a little more pruning of code trying to simplify things. What I found that removing redux from the equation fixes the issue. By simply doing below, the lag disappears. This leads me to believe it has something to do with Redux/RTK.

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
 getListData().then(setListData) 
}, []);
```

Comment: What does `fetchListData` do?

Comment: fetchListData is a thunk that makes a network request. "return await getListData();"

Comment: Please share the code. All your problems could be in there and we could just be guessing.

Comment: React Native UI seems to freeze on API calls. This seems to be a bug multiple people are encountering. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution, @IAmNotANumber!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes running the code after interactions/animations completed solves the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    dispatch(fetchListData());
  });
}, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: This looked promising but unfortunately it did not work for the situation I have.

Comment: Ok just for check can you add delay manually by giving setTimeout 3000 and see how it behave?